# Algorithm that finds the shortest even distance from a vertex s in a graph G to all other vertices.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

G is a connected, undiercted and unweighted graph, and s is some vertex ("source vertex").

For example, let's say the distance between u,v in G is 3, but there is a path of length 8 to v from u, so the algorithm should say that the distance between u,v is 8.

I thought of creating a new graph with same vertices with new edges, but I couldn't find the right ones.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would something like $u\to \color{red}a\to b\to c\to \color{red}a\to d\to v$ be valid? (I am asking because not all authors distinguish walks, trails, and paths the same way)

Comment: Is the graph guaranteed to not be bipartite?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It can be, G can be any undirected connected graph.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, it is valid, it doesn't necessarily have to be simple path.

Answer (score 1):

Use a modification of Dijkstra, where you separate infor mation for odd and even distances:

1. To each node, add field $d_0$ and $d_1$. Initailly set $d_0(v)\leftarrow \infty$ and $d_1(v)\leftarrow\infty$ for all $v$
2. Set $d_0(s)\leftarrow 0$ and push $(s,1)$ to a queue.
3. Pop $(v,t)$ from the queue
4. For all neighbours $w$ of $v$: if $d_{t\bmod 2}(w)=\infty$, set $d_{t\bmod 2}(w)\leftarrow t$ and push $(w,t+1)$ to the queue.
5. If the queue is not empty, go back to step 3. Otherwise terminate. For each node $v$, $d_0(v)$ is the length of the shortest *walk* of even length from $s$ to $v$.

(It may be worth noting that the queue can be realized by an additional field of type pointer-to-node in each node)

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, Can you explain these lines: Set d0(s)←0 and push (s,1) to a queue.

Pop (v,t) from the queue